# Application Crashes Whenever I Try To Save Data In An SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I was learning about SQLite Database in Android from a blog. Using that, I wrote this DatabaseHelperClass.java to perform database operations. Unfortunately, whenever I click the button to save the data, it crashes the application and restarts it. Have a look at my code:

```
package com.arpansircar.loginandregistration.model

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.IO
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.lang.Exception

class DatabaseHelperClass(context: Context): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    companion object{
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "UserAccountInfo"
        const val TABLE_USER_INFO = "user_info"
        const val FIRST_NAME = "first_name"
        const val LAST_NAME = "last_name"
        const val USERNAME = "user_name"
        const val USER_PASSWORD = "user_password"
    }

override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?){
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        val createUserInfoTable = ("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_USER_INFO (" +
                "$FIRST_NAME TEXT" +
                "$LAST_NAME TEXT " +
                "$USERNAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY" +
                "$USER_PASSWORD TEXT"
                )
        p0?.execSQL(createUserInfoTable)
    }
}

override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        p0!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_USER_INFO")
        onCreate(p0)
    }
}

fun insertUser(databaseModelClass: DatabaseModelClass): Long{
    val p0 = this.writableDatabase
    val contentValues = ContentValues()
    contentValues.put(FIRST_NAME, databaseModelClass.firstName)
    contentValues.put(LAST_NAME, databaseModelClass.lastName)
    contentValues.put(USERNAME, databaseModelClass.userName)
    contentValues.put(USER_PASSWORD, databaseModelClass.userPassword)
    var databaseInsertionResult = -1L

    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        databaseInsertionResult = p0.insert(TABLE_USER_INFO, null, contentValues)
    }

    p0.close()
    return databaseInsertionResult
}

fun displayAllUsers(): List<DatabaseModelClass>{
    val userList: ArrayList<DatabaseModelClass> = ArrayList()
    val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_USER_INFO"
    val p0 = this.readableDatabase
    val cursor: Cursor?

    try {
        cursor = p0.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
    }

    catch (e: Exception){
        p0.execSQL(selectQuery)
        return userList
    }

    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var userName: String
    var userPassword: String

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FIRST_NAME))
            lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LAST_NAME))
            userName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(USERNAME))
            userPassword = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(USER_PASSWORD))
            val databaseModelClass = DatabaseModelClass(firstName, lastName, userName, userPassword)
            userList.add(databaseModelClass)
        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
    }
    cursor.close()
    return userList
  }
}
```

Here's the Activity code which I'm using to insert a user into the database. Apart from this, I do not have any other interaction with the database.

```
private void insertDataIntoDatabaseMethod(){
        DatabaseHelperClass databaseHelperClass = new DatabaseHelperClass(this);
        long status = databaseHelperClass.insertUser(new DatabaseModelClass(firstName, lastName, userName, userPassword));
        if (status > -1)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Details Inserted Into Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I suspect I'm getting errors because I'm trying to insert details within the database before actually creating the database with the help of onCreate method in the DatabaseHelperClass. However, I'm not very sure.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Edit: So I removed the Coroutines and performed a few other changes but it still shows the error as

```
2020-07-24 22:41:59.137 19597-19597/com.arpansircar.loginandregistration E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: user_info
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have syntax errors in SQL strings - commas and parenthesis e.g. shall be like:

```
val createUserInfoTable = ("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_USER_INFO +" (" +
                FIRST_NAME +" TEXT, " +
                LAST_NAME +" TEXT, " +
                USERNAME " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT)"
                )

p0!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_USER_INFO)

val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_USER_INFO
```

Comment: I performed the required. But it still displays the error as ```2020-07-24 22:41:59.137 19597-19597/com.arpansircar.loginandregistration E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: user_info```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial issue was using the coroutine in `onCreate`, since it meant the database might not be initialized when that method returns. Since you tried to insert immediately after constructing the object (and thus before the `IO` scheduler could run the coroutine) it ended up causing an error and leaves the program in an undefined state.

The issue presumably persists because `onCreate` is only called for the initial creation of the database, meaning that even after fixing `onCreate` the initialization code won't be called while the physical database file still exists.

You should delete the file from the android filesystem and see if that solves your issue.